# Can you take a CSS snapshot of the styles applied to a page?

Tags: css, performance, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a page where a few javascript attributes load and modify the classes on various DOM elements. I was wondering if there was a means to "stop" the processing to see what is being applied. It would be amazing if there was a timeline feature, similar to the Javascript timeline in the Chrome Dev tools.

My apologies if this has been answered or is not technically a CSS question. I think others would benefit from a simple explanation to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I asked Paul Irish over Twitter and he said to use "Local Modifications" in the Sources tab. When selecting a Source sidebar content node, you can right click it to find this option.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor DOM changes via DOM Change Breakpoints or MutationObservers.

See this related post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42914274/1669860